# Display the intersect of multiple categories

Tags: catalog

This is less a question of *how* as much as it's a question of *how ill-advised is this*?

For simplicity, let's say the store sells bicycle parts.

Basically, the client would like have parts categorized under three main categories: manufacturer, type, and "bicycle type"(IE Road, Mountain, etc).

So: A wheel is manufactured by Mavic but more specifically falls under the "Mavic Pro" category. It's type is clearly "wheel" but it is more specifically a road front wheel. It then would road bikes in the racing category.

I am unaware of any built-in filtering mechanism in Magento to solve this, and I'm also wondering about the advisability of it (and if it's a poor idea, what are some alternatives?)

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this is as follows:

#### First

'Override' (actually replace) `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` in the `app/code/local/mage` directory, adding a method `addAnotherCategoryFilter`:

```
protected $categoryFilterCount = 1;
public function addAnotherCategoryFilter(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category)
{

    $filters = $this->_productLimitationFilters;
    $tName = "cat_index{$this->categoryFilterCount}";
    $conditions = array(
        "{$tName}.product_id=e.entity_id",
        $this->getConnection()->quoteInto("{$tName}.store_id=?", $this->getStoreId()));
    if (isset($filters['visibility']) && !isset($filters['store_table'])) {
        $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
            ->quoteInto("{$tName}.visibility IN(?)", $filters['visibility']);
    }
    $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
        ->quoteInto("{$tName}.category_id = ?",$category->getId());
    if (isset($filters['category_is_anchor'])) {
        $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
            ->quoteInto("{$tName}.is_parent=?", $filters['category_is_anchor']);
    }

    $joinCond = join(' AND ', $conditions);
    $this->getSelect()->join(
        array("{$tName}" => $this->getTable('catalog/category_product_index')),
        $joinCond,
        NULL
    );


    return $this;
}
```

#### Second

Observe for the event `catalog_product_collection_load_before` which send an `$observer` that has a collection inside it. For each category you wish to filter by, run the `addAnotherCategoryFilter` function.

#### Summary

The eventual SQL query generated by this should look similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
    e . *,
    cat_index.position AS cat_index_position,
    price_index.price,
    price_index.tax_class_id,
    price_index.final_price,
    IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
        LEAST(price_index.min_price,
                price_index.tier_price),
        price_index.min_price) AS minimal_price,
    price_index.min_price,
    price_index.max_price,
    price_index.tier_price
FROM
    catalog_product_entity AS e
        INNER JOIN
    catalog_category_product_index AS cat_index ON cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id = 1 AND cat_index.visibility IN (2 , 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '6' AND cat_index.is_parent = 1
        INNER JOIN
    catalog_product_index_price AS price_index ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
        INNER JOIN
    catalog_category_product_index AS cat_index1 ON cat_index1.product_id = e.entity_id AND cat_index1.store_id = 1 AND cat_index1.visibility IN (2 , 4) AND cat_index1.category_id = '8' AND cat_index1.is_parent = 1
        INNER JOIN
    catalog_category_product_index AS cat_index2 ON cat_index2.product_id = e.entity_id AND cat_index2.store_id = 1 AND cat_index2.visibility IN (2 , 4) AND cat_index2.category_id = '12' AND cat_index2.is_parent = 1
ORDER BY cat_index.position ASC
LIMIT 2
```

#### Why did you...?

> Override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` the bad way?

I found that the collection returned by `getCollection()` in the observer was not the rewritten one. I'm not certain why that happened, but I believe it's because somewhere in the core code the Model's being instantiated by non-standard (IE not `Mage::getModel...`) means.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to solve that not via categories, but use attributes instead.

Have also a look at the built-in layered navigation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work

Comment: The issue with attributes is that (as far as I understand) There's no possibility to add hierarchy to the attribute.

Comment: This isn't ideal, but it looks to be the best built-in way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Use another attribute** - create an attribute for **frontend filtering purposes only**, that effectively **combines** all of these manufacturer, types, etc. into more generalized categories.

It's more work, sure, but *without an inheritance mechanism* or nesting function for attributes, this is how it should be managed.

*Source: myself, when I was managing a vitamins ecommerce store and they wanted to merchandise only 3 generalized product types when there were 10 specific types.*

**Change your existing attribute** to a multi-select data-type. That way any one product can have multiple brands.

Comment: It's possible that I'm misunderstanding your recommendation, but if I have a product that needs to show up when filtering for the brand "Trek" and also the _sub brand_ "Project One" that I should create another attribute called "sub brand"?

Comment: Exactly. You would create an attribute that has a one-to-many relationship. These don't have to be a cartesian product, e.g. don't create an attr called 'Trek - Project One'. Rather, group them together by more high-level characteristics.

Comment: So your recommendation would be to create a second product attribute for a "sub brand"-level value, correct?

**edit**: enter means post! ugh! Anyway, I'm not sure how I would group these two product attributes together.

Comment: You could also change your current `brand` attribute to  a multi-select so that each product could have more than one brand associated with it.

Comment: If I'm going to fake the hierarchy, I think each "level" of it needs to be separated, such that sub brands are only visible when a brand is selected.

Comment: I'm interested to see your final solution!

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me though this whole discussion, Phil (I'm guessing that's your first name). I'll definitely report back.

Comment: You asked to see my final solution, @philwinkle. If you like, you can see it below (it's the selected answer).